# Как можно привязать скидку к пользователю?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть скидка на woocommerce

function woo_discount_total(WC_Cart $cart) {

```
$woo_current_price = $cart->subtotal; // Текущая итоговая сумма

if($woo_current_price >= 10000) {

    $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.05; // 0.05 - это 5%
    $cart->add_fee("Скидка в 5% за заказ на сумму от 10 000 рублей ", -$discount);

} elseif($woo_current_price > 10000) {

    $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.05; // 0.05 - это 5%
    $cart->add_fee("Скидка в 5% за заказ на сумму более 10 000 рублей ", -$discount);

}
```

}

add_action("woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees" , "woo_discount_total");

Вопрос: можно ли скидку привязать к пользователю, чтоб при разовой покупке в 10000 руб. скидка в 5% уже была постоянная?

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте новый метод:

```
public function get_customer_total_order() {
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => - 1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => array( 'shop_order' ),
        'post_status' => array( 'wc-completed' )
    ) );

    $total = 0;
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
        $total += $order->get_total();
    }

    return $total;
}
```

Добавьте условие в существующий код:

```
elseif( get_customer_total_order() > 10000 ) { 

    $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.05; // 0.05 - это 5%
    $cart->add_fee( "Сумма ваших предыдущих заказов превышает 10 000 рублей, действует скидка в 5% на данный заказ", -$discount );    
}
```